# Error genereting .tagger file in stanford nlp?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Please can you tell me where I make mistake during generating .tagger file? I have create a properties .props file and also have .csv file that is contain about 50000 word for macedonian language and there gramatical meaning.
This two files .props and .csv are located in the root of the stanford model that I downloaded. To generate the .tagger file I use command prompt with the following command:

```
java -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -props mkbase.csv.props
```

But when it start to generate it take to me Reflection exception:

> Exception ReflectionLoading$Reflection Loading Reflection Exception:Error loading edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.OWLQNMinimazer

and other additional lines related with MaxentTagger.

Answer (score 0):

In your properties file, change `search = owlqn` to `search = qn` and this issue should go away.